# How to merge an array with a list in immutable.js

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have a List and an array. I want to merge them by an offset.

```
list = List([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
arr = [7, 8, 9];

// I expect some operation like this to make the list to be [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]:
list = list.merge(arr, 2)
```

I don't know how to deal with it. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Wouldn't merging result in 1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9 ? Maybe you're looking for something different

Comment: Merge by an offset? What does that even mean?

Comment: @Phiter This, I want to merge by an offset. by default, the list.merge will return something like[7, 8, 9, 4, 5], but I would like to have something like [1, 2, 7, 8, 9]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you look for are the following two methods:

- [`Collection.slice()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/slice) which will cut the list from `0` to `2` in your example, effectively offsetting the merging.
- [`List.concat()`](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/concat) which can then be used to merge the array into the list.

You can then chain them together, like this to produce the desired result:

```js
list = Immutable.List([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
arr = [7, 8, 9];

list = list.slice(0, 2).concat(arr);
console.log(list)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```